# Targeting specific material by name in the imported model

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to select a particular material in the imported model (via Collada loader) in Three.js. I know this can be done with the `getChildByName` method but it just doesn't work for me. I couldn't find any working example with this method included, either.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load('myModel.dae', function ( collada ) {
    model = collada.scene;

    var myMaterial = model.getChildByName( 'materialName', true );
    myMaterial.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: true } );
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```js
collada.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child.material && child.material.name === 'materialName' ) {

        child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: true } );

    }

} );
```

Comment: Thanks, that (obviously) worked. Do you mind explaining in what situation `getChildByName` method should be used?

Comment: Hi @mrdoop it says `THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy is not a function` what i have to do ??

Comment: Updated answer to latest version of the API.